# Date get in angular 4 from webapi

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, asp.net-web-api2, angular4-forms

**Only date Get in Angular 4 From WebApi**

```
publish Date Get from webApi <br>
<PublishDate>2018-03-02T00:00:00</PublishDate><br>
```

**typescript Class:**

```
export class IResource {
    ResourceId: number;
    ResourceTitle: string;
    Description: string;
    PublishDate?: Date;
    ImgUrl: string;  
}
```

**Service:**

```
GetResourceById(resourceId) {
    this.appServiceManager.libGet("Resource/" + resourceId).
        subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.resource = response;            
           }

        }, (error: any) => {
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

**Html File:**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 noPadding">Publish Date</div>
   <div class="col-md-8 noPadding">
      <p-calendar name="PublishDate" [(ngModel)]="resource.PublishDate" 
          dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
   </div>
```

**Api Service to get publish Date**

```
public ResourceDTO Find(int id)
{
    //get resource get by id
    Resource dbresource = _db.Resources.Where(m => m.ResourceId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    ResourceDTO resourcesDTO = Mapper.Map<ResourceDTO>(dbresource);[enter image description here][1]

    return resourcesDTO;

}
```

**Publish date box**

[image: a]

Comment: do you know about pipe in angular?

Comment: my problem is resolved by date piping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please explain what you exactly want and I give you belove solution as my understanding

maybe this code will help you

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" max="{{todaysDate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" #myDate [value]="your model | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
                                           (input)="your model=$event.target.value" />
```

Comment: api get date time both but i would to display only date                       (2018-04-28 16:57:18.257)